# DynamoDB BatchLoad returning "Provided list of item keys contains duplicates"

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

My input for batchload is a set but it's giving me the error `Provided list of item keys contains duplicates`. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB is telling you that you tried to write two items with the same **key**. I don't know how exactly you used a *set* in your code, but maybe you ended up with two different updates setting the same key to two **different** values? This is also not allowed, though seemingly different updates, they update the same key.